# Obtain value from multiple criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

Goal: Obtain cost of asset based on type and year.

Sheet1

```
    A            B       C       D          E 
1  YEAR         YEAR    CD2     TYPE       Cost      
2  Prior2005    2003    TRUCK   COMBO      #DIV/0!  
3  2005         2005    TRUCK   CONVEYOR    FALSE
4  2012         2012    TRUCK   CONVEYOR    #N/A
5  2014         2014    TRUCK   CONVEYOR
```

Sheet2
Range Name = Cost_Each

```
YEAR    Tractor, Flatbed(w/ Piggy), Flatbed(wo/ piggy), Conveyor, Combo
2015    2800    2000    2600    3500    3500
2014    4000    4100    2600    3500    3500
2013    7500    4100    1450    6700    6700
2012    7500    4100    1450    6700    6700
2011    7500    4100    1450    N/A N/A
2010    7500    4100    1450    N/A N/A
2009    7500    4100    1450    15200   15200
2008    7500    8500    1450    15200   15200
2007    7500    8500    1450    15200   15200
2006    7500    8500    1450    15200   15200
2005    7500    8500    1450    15200   15200
Prior 2005  7500    8500    1450    15200   15200
```

I have tried the following on Sheet1 to get the cost (unsuccessfully):

```
Row 2 
=LOOKUP((Cost_Each!A$2:A$15=A2)/(Cost_Each!B$2:B$15=D2),(Cost_Each!B$3:M$14))
Row 3
=IFERROR(INDEX(Cost_Each,MATCH(D3,Cost_Each,0),MATCH(A3,Cost_Each,0)),"FALSE")
Row 4
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A17=Cost_Each!A3:A14),--(D2:D17=Cost_Each!B2:M2),--(Cost_Each!B3:M14))
Row 5
=INDEX(Cost_Each!B3:M14,SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=Cost_Each!A3:A14),--(D:D=Cost_Each!B2:M2),0))
```

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what CD2 is supposed to do - is this perhaps just the table for Trucks, and you have a separate table for, say, Cars? That is, right now, you're only actually looking at the Type & the Year.

So assuming your Cost_Each range is Sheet2!A1:A13 like this [images grabbed from @Jeeped's previous answer],

[image: INDEX MATCH header and row]

... and your summary table on Sheet1A1:E5 is like this,

[image: INDEX MATCH header and row]

If yes, this is very straightforward with a simple INDEX / MATCH / MATCH combo (note two MATCH's). Like so:

```
=INDEX(Cost_Each,MATCH(A2,INDEX(Cost_Each,0,1),0),MATCH(D2,INDEX(Cost_Each,1,0)))
```

This says:

Take the index of the Two-D array. Pull the result from the cell where: (1) The row matches the year in the first column of the Two-D array [INDEX(Cost_Each,0,1) says: give all the rows of the first column of Cost_Each)]; and (2) the column matches the Type in the first row of the Two-D array.

If I have misunderstood the way your data please clarify by editing your original question.

Comment: @Jeeped From the little fuzzball on America's Toque. [Any way you could fix my image links? Havent used them before an not sure why I can't get them working...]

Comment: You're too close to the border if you don't spell touque with two u's. Get yourself a little close to the 60th parallel and clear your head.

Comment: Thank you for the answer however I am getting an #N/A result. I clicked on the function and it knows the correct row # but the second MATCH function for the type (D column) is giving me the #N/A result.

Comment: DG24 Are you sure the result is actually there? Did you spell it the same in both? No trailing/leading spaces? @Jeeped - don't blame on lack of patriotism that which can be attributed to poor spelling.

Comment: Yes. No spaces, spelling is in the same. I copied info from here into a new workbook and get same #N/A result.  Somehow it doesn't know what the column should be.

Comment: Are you sure your Cost_Each named range properly refers to the entire table, and that the first row of the table is your headers there? If Cost_Each actually starts with, say, a blank row, this will refer to that blank row instead of the header row.

Comment: It is strange. I deleted the range name re-entered it and the result was "COMBO" for E2.  So I deleted the range name again and re-entered it again and the result is back to the #N/A in E2.  The Cost_Each range is $A$1 to $F$13. From time to time we have had issues with Excel on the computers here.  I am using Office 2013.

Comment: I figured out my answer.  Thank you Grade 'Eh' Bacon and Jeeped for your help.  Here is the formula I used.  I just kept trying different things.   =INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$P$13,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$13,0),MATCH($D2,Sheet2!$B$1:$P$1,0))